# Configure Memory (Photos) titles to have a specific date format (M-D-Y or Y-M-D)

Tags: macos, photos, memory, photos.app

Is it possible to change the way Photos is naming the memories?
Basically, it is quite stupid to name it using Day-Month-Year order, since an export of the memories using the option "Create subfolder with the name of the memory" will export the pictures in a folder that cannot be sorted by date later on...

Let's say I have multiple memories of 2018 on the 1st day of each month, then the generated folder will be sorted as follows:

- 1 April 2018
- 1 March 2018
- 1 September 2018
- 2 January 2018
- 2 April 2018

That's pretty annoying, isn't it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: unfortunately that sorting works by using the first then second character, ie 1A, 1M, 1S, followed by 2, and not by actual date. It sorts by name not date

Comment: That's precisely the problem, thanks for reformulating.

Answer (score 1):

if you open the folder in Finder it can be made to list the date created. Open a finder window and click on the button that looks like a gear with the word action under it. The last entry is 'Show View Options'. You can click on this and you'll get a new pane where you can select what columns to display in a finder window. Be sure to select Date Created. You can then sort the files by date created and separate them however you see fit.

Comment: No, that won't work. I am talking about Memory Album Export here, so basically Photos is creating new files and not in the correct order anyway, so this 'Date Created' won't do the trick.